# Setting name of initial task in a vxworks RTP

Tags: vxworks

When you spawn a new vxworks task using taskSpawn, you get to set the task name:

```
char name[16] = "tFooBar";    
taskSpawn(name, 100, VX_FP_TASK,STACK_SIZE,  foo, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

You can do this both to spawn a new task within the kernel or within an RTP.
What I cant figure out is how to set the task name of the **initial** RTP task, which appears to always be allocated `iMyRtp` (assuming the RTP is MyRtp.vxe).

I cant believe this isn't possible, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to just spawn a new, named, task immediately on entry to the RTP, and perform the work in this task.

The Initial task should then be exited using `taskExit()` to ensure that the RTP is not removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is hard coded in the OS code. I'm sure you will be able to change the task name if you have access and willing to change the OS code.
Any specific reason you wants to do this?

Comment: The fundamental reason is because I am spawning many instances of an RTP, and I want to be able to distinguish between them.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting requirement,... If you change the RTP library source code then you will have to put some logic in there to figure out different names. Please share your requirement if you do not mind,... I'm sure you must have thought of this but simplest suggesiton is rename the .vxe file everytime before launching it.